# Cannot read property 'paused' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a customised video in html and css. When I try to click PLAY button the following error pops up: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paused' of null

I also tried to use document.getReady instead of window onload but the error still occurs. Any idea why is this?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //video
  var video = document.getElementById("video-container__video");
  //Buttons 
  var playButton = document.getElementById("video-controls__play-pause");
  var muteButton = document.getElementById("video-controls__mute");
  var fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("video-controls__full-screen");

  //sliders
  var seekbar = document.getElementById("video-controls__seek-bar");
  var volumebar = document.getElementById("video-controls__volume-bar");

  //event listener for the play and pause button

  playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (video.paused == true) {
      video.play();

      //button text will change to Pause
      playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else {
      //pause the video
      video.pause();
      //button will update its text to play
      playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <!-- Video -->
    <video class="video-container__video" width="640" height="365">
      <source src='_assets/media/big_buck_bunny.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
<div id="video-controls">
  <button type="button" id="video-controls__play-pause">Play</button>
  <input type="range" id="video-controls__seek-bar" value="0">
  <button type="button" id="video-controls__mute">Mute</button>
  <input type="range" id="video-controls__volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
  <button type="button" id="video-controls__full-screen">Full-Screen</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the element with ID `video-container__video`? Please show that part as well...

Comment: @FZs <div class="video-container">
    <!-- Video -->
    <video class="video-container__video" width="640" height="365">
      <source src='_assets/media/big_buck_bunny.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    </video>

Comment: `class="video-container__video" ` it's a class not a ID `getElementById` gets element by id

Comment: omg right!!!!! thank you!! I started to write classes but changed to ids at some point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that your video element has a class `video-container__video`, while you try to access it by ID.

This results in `video` being `null`, and you get an error, when you try to read the `paused` property of it.

Ways to fix the problem:

1. Change the class to an ID!
   Classes intended to create 'groups' of similar elements, not for identifying a single element.
   Or:
2. If you have only one element with that class, change this line:

   ```
   var video=document.getElementById("video-container__video")
   ```

   to either of the following:

   ```
   var video=document.getElementByClassName("video-container__video")[0]
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   var video=document.querySelector(".video-container__video")
   ```
3. If you had more than one elements with that class, you would have to use a loop (but that's probably not the case...):

   ```
   var videos=document.getElementByClassName("video-container__video")

   for(video of videos){
       //Do something with each element
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to get the `video` by id but it has a class. Try with:

```
var video = document.querySelector(".video-container__video");
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //video
  var video = document.querySelector(".video-container__video");
  console.log(video);
  //Buttons 
  var playButton = document.getElementById("video-controls__play-pause");
  var muteButton = document.getElementById("video-controls__mute");
  var fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("video-controls__full-screen");

  //sliders
  var seekbar = document.getElementById("video-controls__seek-bar");
  var volumebar = document.getElementById("video-controls__volume-bar");

  //event listener for the play and pause button

  playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (video.paused == true) {
      video.play();

      //button text will change to Pause
      playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else {
      //pause the video
      video.pause();
      //button will update its text to play
      playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <!-- Video -->
  <video class="video-container__video" width="640" height="365">
      <source src='_assets/media/big_buck_bunny.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
  <div id="video-controls">
    <button type="button" id="video-controls__play-pause">Play</button>
    <input type="range" id="video-controls__seek-bar" value="0">
    <button type="button" id="video-controls__mute">Mute</button>
    <input type="range" id="video-controls__volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
    <button type="button" id="video-controls__full-screen">Full-Screen</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change the video html element `class="video-container__video"` to `id="video-container__video"` because you can't pass class to getElementById and you should only pass Id to it. this explains the null reference error

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and print what playButton holds? It says there is a type error and there must be something you are missing i.e. accessing wrong ids/classes. Just try and print what it contains and check the variable and elements you are trying to access the element from. `Try change the class to id in the main video element`